# Re-ordering alpha-numerical array

Tags: arrays, nightwatch.js

As part of my **nightwatchjs** testing, I have two arrays that I'm running a comparison on, so that if they are the same then the test will pass.

So my first array is;
`C-Crosser',
  'C-Zero',
  'C1',
  'C2',
  'C3',
  'C3 Aircross',
  'C3 Picasso',
  'C3 Pluriel',
  'C3 XTR',
  'C4',
  'C4 Cactus',
  'C4 Picasso',
  'C4 SpaceTourer',
  'C5',
  'C6',
  'C8',
  'DS3',
  'DS4',
  'DS5',
  'Dispatch Combi',`

and the second array is;

```
'C1',
  'C2',
  'C3',
  'C3 Aircross',
  'C3 Picasso',
  'C3 Pluriel',
  'C3 XTR',
  'C4',
  'C4 Cactus',
  'C4 Picasso',
  'C4 SpaceTourer',
  'C5',
  'C6',
  'C8',
  'C-Crosser',
  'C-Zero',
  'Dispatch Combi',
  'DS3',
  'DS4',
  'DS5',
```

So it appears that the alpha-numeric values need sorting (C1 for example is listed **after** C-Crosser in the first array but **before** in the second array) as an entry with a number in it is sorted differently in the 2 arrays. Ideally the 2nd array would match the first.

Please note that these arrays are dynamic, so I can't use 'move' an array entry.

Also, I thought

```
myarray.sort(function (a, b) {
   return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
 });
```

might work, but it didn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `options` for the [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to achieve this. In particular `numeric: true, ignorePunctuation: true` like so:

```js
const data = [ 'C-Crosser', 'C-Zero', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3 Aircross', 'C3 Picasso', 'C3 Pluriel', 'C3 XTR', 'C4', 'C4 Cactus', 'C4 Picasso', 'C4 SpaceTourer', 'C5', 'C6', 'C8', 'DS3', 'DS4', 'DS5', 'Dispatch Combi' ]

let result = data.sort((a,b) => 
  a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase(), 'en', { 
  numeric: true, ignorePunctuation: true 
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @DarrenHarley you are welcome. If this solved your issue please mark it as the answer so others can find it easier etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be use lodash and method _.differenceWith(first_arr, second_arr, _.isEqual);